# Fill colors in the table cell

Tags: python, html, css, json

I am trying to add colors on basis on my result. If 'UnSuccessfull' - 'red'
If 'Succesfull' - 'green'. 
Issue is that I am directly converting my JSON file to format it in a table using jSON2HTML python library in one line, hence am not sure where and how to fill/add colors. Can anyone please assist?

```
import json
import json2html


file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8-sig')
data_to_be_sent = json.loads(file_content) 
# Convert to table
table = json2html.convert(json = data_to_be_sent)
```

Data to be sent is in table row format. Where and what should I put in to add colors in one of the cell since it shows result

Answer (score 0):

You can add a js file or simplaly a internal js to check values of all td and a simple if else condition can workaround in adding color to respective td for example

```js
$('#mytable tr td').each(function() {
    var tdValue =  $(this).html();
    if (tdValue > 10){
    $(this).css("color", "green");
    }else if (tdValue < 10){
     $(this).css("color", "red");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

this example is just for explaining the concept it might not work but i hope you got my point